# using LEPL to parse a Boolean search query

Tags: python, parsing, boolean, grammar, lepl

I'm trying to write a [LEPL](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/) grammar to describe a Boolean search language.  This is what I have so far:

```
from lepl import *
text = String() | Word()
tail = ~Lookahead('AND') & ~Lookahead('OR') & text
with DroppedSpace():
    andClause = (tail & Lookahead('AND') & Drop('AND') & tail)[1:] > tuple
    orClause = (tail & Lookahead('OR') & Drop('OR') & tail)[1:] > list
    andOrText = (andClause & Lookahead('OR') & Drop('OR') & tail)[1:] > list
    orAndText = (orClause & Lookahead('AND') & Drop('AND') & tail)[1:] > tuple
    oredAnds = (andClause & Lookahead('OR') & Drop('OR') & andClause)[1:] > list
    andedOrs = (orClause & Lookahead('AND') & Drop('AND') & orClause)[1:] > tuple
    query = (oredAnds | andedOrs | orAndText | andOrText | orClause | andClause | text)[:]

query.parse('foo AND bar') # Works
query.parse('"bar none" OR foo') # Works
query.parse('foo AND "bar none" OR baz AND floo') # Works
query.parse('a AND b OR c AND d OR e') # Doesn't work
```

The last `parse` produces this:

```
[[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')], 'OR', 'e']
```

It should produce this:

```
[[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), 'e']]
```

How can I fix this to get the parse I want?  I think it would fix it if I could say "whatever AND whatever" becomes a `tuple`, and "whatever OR whatever" becomes a `list`.

Comment: I think [Delayed()](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/style.html#use-delayed-for-recursive-definitions) may be what I need.  Trying that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** got rid of sloooooow left recursion thanks to [this article](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/abegel/cs164/ll1.html) and added keyword parameters.

```
from lepl import *
def ander(result):
    if len(result) == 2:
        return (result[0], result[1])
    return result[0]
text = String() | Word()
andClausePrime = Delayed()
label = text & Drop(':')
with DroppedSpace():
    parameter = label & text > (lambda r: {r[0]: r[1]})
    andClause = (parameter | text) & andClausePrime > ander
    andClausePrime += (Drop('AND') & (andClause | parameter | text) & andClausePrime)[:]
    expr = andClause | parameter | text
    query = expr & (Drop('OR') & expr)[:]
```

The results:

```
>>> query.parse('a AND b')
[('a', 'b')]
>>> query.parse('a AND b AND c')
[('a', ('b', 'c'))]
>>> query.parse('a AND b AND c AND d')
[('a', ('b', ('c', 'd')))]
>>> query.parse('a AND b AND c AND d OR e AND f')
[('a', ('b', ('c', 'd'))), ('e', 'f')]
>>> query.parse('a AND b AND c AND d OR e OR f')
[('a', ('b', ('c', 'd'))), 'e', 'f']
>>> query.parse('foo AND bar')
[('foo', 'bar')]
>>> query.parse('"bar none" OR foo')
['bar none', 'foo']
>>> query.parse('key:value AND "hey now":5 OR "what is":up')
[({'key': 'value'}, {'hey now': '5'}), {'what is': 'up'}]
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it parse `NOT` expressions as well?